# How to make boxplot using matplotlib when i already have all the information?

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, anaconda

Can you guys help me for my statistics problem?
I'm trying to make Box Plot exactly like this :

[image: 1]

I have all the information to make like :

```
# Median  
medianResult = specificData.median()

# Percentile 25
Q1 = specificData.quantile(0.25)

# Percentile 75
Q3 = specificData.quantile(0.75)


# Reasonable Upper Boundary (RUB)
RUB = Q3 + (1.5 * IQRResult)

# Reasonable Lower Boundary (RLB)
RLB = Q1 - (1.5 * IQRResult)
```

is there any other information do i need to make BoxPlot? and how to make one like exactly from the picture above? Sorry if my english bad.. Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call matplotlib's [`ax.bxp(...)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html) directly. It accepts a list of dictionaries as its first parameter.  Here is an example to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

medianResult = 49
# Percentile 25
Q1 = 44
# Percentile 75
Q3 = 57
IQRResult = Q3 - Q1
# Reasonable Upper Boundary (RUB)
RUB = Q3 + (1.5 * IQRResult)
# Reasonable Lower Boundary (RLB)
RLB = Q1 - (1.5 * IQRResult)

stat_dict1 = {'med': medianResult,
              'q1': Q1,
              'q3': Q3,
              'whislo': RLB,
              'whishi': RUB,
              'fliers': [15, 18],
              'label': 'Example'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bxp(bxpstats=[stat_dict1])
plt.show()
```

[image: example boxplot]